# Example of an algebraic group G defined over k such that G does not contain a Borel subgroup defined over k.

Tags: algebraic-groups

Example of an algebraic group $G$ defined over $k$ but $G$ does not contains a Borel subgroup defined over $k$.

Comment: For reductive groups $G$ would be not quasi-split. This might help lead to an example.